# Adding a column guideline to the editor in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'd like to use column guide line to IntelliJ IDE.
Anybody knows about this?
I couldn't find any solution for the feature?

For example:
[image: Visual Studio with column guideline]

Comment: @Lucas Heneks: you mean that vertical line that shows that line length is 100 (for example) characters at that point?

Comment: @Roman yeah, I'm pretty sure that is what he's talking about.  That's what they call it in visual studio land.

Comment: You may also need to search preferences for "right margin color" and set a color for the right margin. In the Solarized Light scheme, for example, this is left blank.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to configure, then you need:

Go to IDE Settings -> Editor Settings -> Appearance -> Tick `Show right margin`.

Comment: Where the heck is IDE settings?

Comment: @DonLarynx to look up anything quickly (including settings) press `double SHIFT` and start typing in the popup dialogue.

Answer (score 27):

I use Idea 12. You can find the settings here:
First go to:

- File > Settings > IDE Settings > Editor > Appearance
- Verify that "Show right Margin" is checked.

Now go to:

- File > Settings > Project Settings > Code Style > General
- Select your project's Scheme and then the right margin character size.
- From this page you can auto wrap or switch to using the tab character vs. the 4 spaces for indents.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 20):

### [In Intellj idea 13](http://prayag-waves.blogspot.com/search?q=intellij),

**STEP 1 :**
Goto **File-> Settings > Code style > General**

[image: intellij 13 column width]

**STEP 2 :** 
Change *Right margin (columns)* label

**STEP 3 :**
Check on *Wrap when typing reaches right margin.*

**STEP 4 :**
Goto **Editor-> Appearance**, check on **4th label** (*Show right margin*)

[image: show margin]

### output

[image]

Comment: lol, temperature alert in the first screenshot using IntelliJ. Ain't that the truth.

Comment: This is the most accurate answer right now

Comment: In Android Studio 2021.1.1, this is called instead "Hard wrap at" (Editor -> Code Style -> General)

Answer (score 4):

For my IntelliJ version - *IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 (Ultimate Edition)*, on Ubuntu - the setting is named *Visual guides* and can be found at:

*Settings* (CTRL-ALT-S) -> *Editor* -> *Code Style* -> *Visual guides*

[image: Screenshot showing the above settings page, with the "Visual guides" label, "Optional" placeholder, "columns" suffix, and tip "Specify one guide (80) or several (80, 120)]

Comment: They're called Visual Guides in CLion 2022.2.4 as well - I just searched them with the global search. The comma separations for multiple visual guides is supported, although not said explicitly.

Comment: Same for me in IntelliJ IDEA `2023.1 (Ultimate Edition)` on Mac; parent root was `Editor`.  None of the other Answers missing that matched for me, especially ones mentioning anything with "margin".