# how to remove Android Studio background line?

Tags: android-studio

I've used android studio today, and I can't remove the background line:

[image]

How do I remove this line?

Comment: It looks like a 120 char line (margin) marker. It's hinting that your lines are becoming too long. There are standards. With the correct jargon you should be able to remove it, but why?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480826/adding-a-column-guideline-to-the-editor-in-intellij

Answer (score 5):

The line is the "Right Margin" marker line.  It is set to wrap text at a specified character length, when turned on.

To turn on Wrap text at specified character length go to: `File>Settings>Code Styles>General>Wrap` when typing, and set character length amount.

To remove line go to: `File>Settings>IDE Settings>Editor>Appearance>Show Right Margin`.  Uncheck it to remove.

Comment: Hi folks, in the newest Android Studio version this option name it has changed to: "Show hard wrap guide (configured in Code Style options) "

Answer (score 5):

In **Android Studio**

Go to `Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Appearance` -> Uncheck the `Hard Wrap Guide`

[image: hard wrap guide]

Answer (score 4):

## Android Studio 3.0 on os x:

Preference -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show Right Margin

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the settings for this if you go to File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings. Choose Code Style from the list on the left, then General. Change the `Right Margin` attribute to be 0. This'll remove the line.

[image: location image]

Comment: @girin if you believe this to be the correct answer please mark it as accepted and upvote to show your appreciation

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.2 and it appears that the menus have been changed.

To remove the line, go to `Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > Show right margin`.

To adjust the right margin where text wraps, go to `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Default Options` and change the number in `Right margin`.