# Why is there a black line crossing the screen in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I noticed there is a black, thin line crossing the screen in IntelliJ IDEA editor:

[image]

I imagine this is a "hint" that tells you when to introduce a new line if the current line is getting huge, but I am not sure about this theory.

Is that the reason?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480826/adding-a-column-guideline-to-the-editor-in-intellij

Comment: Probably because the Old Printer cant print if the text passes that line. IMO the code readability is not the main reason for sure (no reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line marks the area where all code is wrapped when you use the auto-formatter if you have it configured that way. IntelliJ will insert line breaks so that there are no overlappings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems it put there for help you to make your code more readable.
When you reach it, it's better to go to new line to avoid long lines in your code
So... Yes! You're Right!

Comment: Nonsense -- code readability suffers from random line breaks and avoiding long-lines is a personal preference that has nothing to do with readability.